# Calculate X and Y velocity from image rotation of mouse

Tags: java, rotation, mouse

So I have a Java2D game when I have to rotate a cannon to the mouse's direction and save the angle. It works but I have the real issue. I can't calculate correct X and Y velocity from this answer i got from this equation:

```
double angle = Math.atan2(centerY - c.mouseY, centerX - c.mouseX) - Math.PI / 2;
```

then i use this equation:

```
int x = (int) Math.acos(c.rotation*Math.PI/180);
int y = (int) Math.sin(c.rotation*Math.PI/180);
```

I don't get the right velocity for y. can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because your using cosine when calculating y value. Shouldn't it be sine?

Comment: Nope still didn't work. I have a reference guide to this and it uses an integer for rotation, but the problem is that i don't get an integer for rotation I get a double.

Comment: Nevermind for the x velocity i got that but the y velocity still doesnt work

Comment: What is being stored under c.rotation? How do you want velocity to be calculated? Maybe you don't need to calculate any angles and all you need is to normalize vector (and then optionally scale it) like this: double x = mouseX / sqrt (mouseX^2 + mouseY^2), double y = mouseY / sqrt (mouseX^2 + mouseY^2).

Comment: That kinda works but it doesn't go in the direction it's supposed to go in. c.rotation holds the value from the angle variable.

Comment: If only the direction is an issue, than you probably need to invert and/or offset values before normalizing them. Try do it in the way that you did it when you wanted to calculate the angle: double posX = centerX - c.mouseX, double posY = centerY - c.mouseY. Then replace mouseX with posX and mouseY with posY in previous equations.

Comment: Well whats a better way to calculate mouse angle from my object by getting a bigger number for calculating velocity with because my angle variable is always -4 to 0~1-ish?

Comment: I would recommend normalizing instead of using a trigonometry, because it should be faster, no matter what the value of angle is.

Comment: Well I just used Math.toDegrees(angle) and then guess that worked. Thanks though for trying to help me.